# Javascript remove all get variables with history push state

Tags: javascript, url, history, pushstate

How can I remove all get variables with javascript history push state?

**It should work in the following cases:**

```
http://example.com/slug1/slug2/index.php?myvar=1&myvar2=4
http://example.com/index.php?myvar=1&myvar2=4
http://example.com/slug1/slug2/?myvar=1&myvar2=4
http://example.com/slug2/?myvar=1&myvar2=4
```

And after it should look like this:

```
http://example.com/slug1/slug2/index.php
http://example.com/index.php
http://example.com/slug1/slug2/
http://example.com/slug2/
```

Maybe like a function like this:

```
function removeGetVariablesFromUrl() {
// Do stuff
}
```

It should not return the address with the change, it should change the actual url in the address field without reload the page.

Comment: Yes I can. I found an answer and added it. It was really simple.

Comment: I stand corrected, although it doesn't seem to run for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dynamic way of doing this in javascript:

```
var url = window.location.href;

if(url.indexOf("?") != -1) {
    var resUrl = url.split("?");

    if(typeof window.history.pushState == 'function') {
        window.history.pushState({}, "Hide", resUrl[0]);
    }
}
```

This will take you current URL and remove anything after and including a '?' symbol (which indicates $_GET variables)

Answer (score 2):

**It was really simple:**

```
function removeGetVariablesFromUrl(my_url) {
    my_url = "An url without get variables";
    history.pushState({}, 'The title', my_url);
}
```